# Filterable with RecyclerView is cancelling when pressing checkmark key on keyboard

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-filterable

I have a RecyclerView with a simple String based list of names. I added the implements Filterable to my class and I can search/filter the results using the search bar. The problem comes in when pressing the arrow/enter key on the soft keyboard. When you do that it completely cancels the search and goes back to the full list of names. I have searched through examples of how to use the Filterable class and I am completely in line with all the results I have seen. I just can't figure out how to make it not cancel when hitting the checkmark/enter button on the keyboard.
[image]

The filtering works as you can see, but that darn arrow key cancels the search results and takes me back to the full list view.

Here is the relevant parts of the code if it is needed...

```
public class VegetableListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VegetableListAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
//...
private ArrayList<VegetableName> allNames;
private ArrayList<VegetableName> filteredNames;

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
         super(view);
         name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
         //...
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final VegetableName name = filteredNames.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(name.getName());
}

//...
@Override
public void getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
         @Override
         protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
             FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
             String term = charSequence.toString();
             Log.d("VegetableListAdapter", "Searching for string: " + term);
             if(term.isEmpty()) {
                  filteredNames = allNames;
                  results.values = allNames;
                  results.count = allNames.size();
             } else {
                  ArrayList<VegetableName> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                  for(VegetableName name : allNames) {
                      if(name.getName().toLowerCase().contains(term.toLowerCase()) {
                      filteredList.add(name);
                  }
                  filteredNames = filteredList;
             }
             results.values = filteredNames;
             results.count = filteredNames.size();
             return results;
      }
      @Override
      protected void publishResults(CharSequence sequence, FilterResults results) {
          Log.d("VegetableListAdapter", "publishing results of: " + sequence);
          filteredNames = (ArrayList<VegetableName>) filterResults.values;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
 };
```

}

Calling the filter is done in the Activity here...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.vegetable_list, menu);

    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == android.R.id.home) {
        if(!searchView.isIconified()) {
            searchView.setIconified(true);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return id == R.id.action_search || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(!searchView.isIconified()) {
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_left, R.anim.slide_to_right);
}
```

I am crazy stuck here, I don't understand why that stupid arrow button is causing the search to cancel and lose the results. Please help me out. Thank you

Logcat output of above added Log.d lines...
[image]

Comment: `"but that darn checkmark cancels"` - what "checkmark" do you really mean?

Comment: Whoops, I meant that darn arrow. Will edit question. Sorry

Comment: ok where do you call `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)`? only in `OnQueryTextListener#onQueryTextChange`?

Comment: It's in the activity, I forgot to include that part. Updated with code from Activity. Sorry... again :)

Comment: ok try to `Log.d` the value of the parameter passed to `performFiltering` method, what do you see on the logcat? is it called with empty CharSequence at the end?

Comment: It shows the correct information in logcat... "D/VegetableListAdapter: Searching for string: carrot", "D/VegetableListAdapter: Publishing results of: carrot". But then I hit the stupid arrow button on the keyboard and in no longer logs anything from that, it just starts logging stuff like "V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisibility: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@4190835[]" I added the Log.d to both performFiltering and publishResults

Comment: so there is no empty string? i'll check it

Comment: Added screenshot of logcat output and added where the Log.d lines are in the code.

Comment: tried my favorite [CurrencyAdapter](https://pastebin.com/raw/LEena3pM) but it works ok, base class [here](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) - try to use it and check if it works like you said

Comment: and if it works, try to compare your filter and my filter (in the base class)

Comment: After reviewing your it looks like we are both using very similar methods to achieve the result. I am not using a synchronized lock to synchronize the copy of the arrays. You can hit that arrow key on yours and it won't cancel the search and go back to the full list?

Comment: yes, and what about you? did you try my adapter? maybe it's your software keyboard to blame?

Comment: I think the problem is the searchview I am using is actually in the status bar as an options menu, so the arrow/enter key is doing something different than it normally does.

Comment: I found out what the problem was. The tutorial I used was having me set the searchView.setSearchableInfo param, which changed the way the enter key worked. As soon as I removed that line, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The tutorial I was looking at for this had me add the line

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Which was adding the arrow key to the keyboard. When pressing that it was using the searchableInfo to find results, of course there were none, so it was just going back to the list. Removing that line turned the arrow key into a search key and now it works perfectly.
Just wanted to post this answer in case anyone else runs into this issue.